# form method="post" stopped my Meta refresh from happening

Tags: php, html, css, email

I have a form in a html page,

```
<form method="post" name="myemailform" target="_blank" action="http://xxxxx.com/xxx/gxxif/xx/form-to-email.php">
    <b>Enter your Personal Identification Number / PIN:&nbsp;&nbsp;</b>
    <input name="pincode" type="password" maxlength="4" id="ctl00_cphContent_txtPIN" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="submit" name="pincodesend" value="Next &gt;&gt;" id="ctl00_cphContent_btnSubmit" class="SmallButton">
</form>
```

Now, I have also a `<META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" CONTENT="5">`

and the problem is when I don't use the form its refresh just fine, when i do use it, it stopped my refresh at all.

Is there any way (with no javascript) to fix this from happening?

Answer (score 0):

I think redirecting (301) instead of refreshing will solve the problem.
If you are running PHP on your server:

```
<?php
Header( "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently" ); 
Header( "Location: http://YOUR-WEB.SITE/path/path.php" ); 
?>
```

Comment: I cant understand what you just said, can you please expline?

Comment: Refreshing the page will cause all the data on the inputs be gone. that's why the broswer don't let you refresihng when you'v already typed some info, to avoid loses. if you want to refresh only some parts maybe AJAX will be the right answer for you. P.S: reloading the page (301 redirect) will refresh the hole page, because it's not clinet-side

Comment: cant i overright it? i want to lose the data.... and another thing, i cant use any javascript/ajax or php in my page, only on the server side one.

Comment: Since the "anti refreshing" system is on the client side, we can force the user to load the page from the server side, with PHP for example.
Maybe try this PHP code:
"<? header("Refresh: 5; url=page.php"); ?>"

EDIT:
or maybe this:
<? sleep(5);
header("location:page.php"); ?>

Comment: If you are 100% sure you cant cancle the anti refresh then i have no other way. BUT, i cant put any php tags in my html, i need the client side to be clean (it runs in email).

Comment: If it's runing on email, why would you want to refresh the page? I guess there is no new info since the email data stay the same..
Anyway, you say that you cant use PHP/JS? which mean HTML only? well i dont know how to do this with HTML only, i'm sorry.

Comment: I want to refresh so new data will be downloaded, and i cant use javascript/php beacuse all mail client will delete my inforamtion, so my only thing is html/css3. any one else knows anything? (btw, ty aviv for trying").